# Edition of Mesilat Yesharim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, mesilas-yesharim

Can someone please recommend an edition of Mesilat Yesharim?

I am looking for an edition with the following features.

- All Hebrew
- Nice, clear print
- Elucidations/commentaries for difficult passages
- Highly accurate and without typos

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does "all Hebrew" mean only Hebrew?

Comment: Yes, all means only Hebrew.

Comment: Sorry this does not match all of your criteria, but I have מלכות קודש version ofמסילת  ישרים and it has a very clear print. No commentary though, and I didn't see any typos but don't know if it is "highly accurate". It's sold for e.g. here: https://malchutdavid.co.il/product/%d7%9e%d7%a1%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%aa-%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9d/

Comment: This doesn't meet your criteria either, but you ought to know it exists: the Ramchal's first version of Mesilas Yesharin was written as a dialog between two old friends who meet up again- one ended up a Chakham, the other a Chassid. I find it useful, as it reminds me not to be the Chalham to the exckhsiooof the Chassid.  It to analyze the Middos and forgetting to try to implement them The Ramchal then reorganized it into the chapter version we have now. There are published editions that have both, including cross-references so you can see how the Ramchal treated the topic the first time.

Comment: R itamAr Sxhwartz, Bilvavi Mishkan Evneh, has an edition with his commentary. A 3 volume set.

Comment: Do you have a link to that three volume set?

Comment: And are Malchut David books also sold in the US?